# UIViewController inserted into UINavigationController stack loses UIAppearance settings

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiappearance

I have a UIAppearance set-up for my navigation bars.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [self navigationBarTitleTextAttributes]];



-(NSDictionary *)navigationBarTitleTextAttributes
{
    // UINavigationBar title
    NSNumber *navBarTitleShadowOpacity = [self.personalityDictionary objectForKey:kNavBarTitleShadowOpacity];
    UIColor *navBarTitleColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString: [self.personalityDictionary objectForKey:kNavBarTitleColor] alpha:1.0f];
    UIColor *navBarTitleShadowColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:[self.personalityDictionary objectForKey:kNavBarTitleShadowColor] alpha: [navBarTitleShadowOpacity floatValue]];

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     navBarTitleColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
     navBarTitleShadowColor, UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
     [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
     nil];
}
```

All works perfectly. At one point in my app, I need to insert a view controller into the stack and pop to it.

```
ChatsViewController* chatsViewController = [[ChatsViewController alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *mutableViewControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

[mutableViewControllers insertObject: chatsViewController atIndex: [mutableViewControllers count] - 1];

[self.navigationController setViewControllers: mutableViewControllers animated: NO];

[self.navigationController popToViewController: chatsViewController animated: YES];
```

At this point, the title bar  loses the appearance settings and returns to the default white. Any new view controllers pushed onto the stack also lose their appearance.

What's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

If you Customize this in appDelegate class then this problem will never comes.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
   // Code.........

   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [self navigationBarTitleTextAttributes]]
  }

-(NSDictionary *)navigationBarTitleTextAttributes
 {

// NSNumber *navBarTitleShadowOpacity = [self.personalityDictionary objectForKey:kNavBarTitleShadowOpacity];
 UIColor *navBarTitleColor = [UIColor redColor];//: [self.personalityDictionary objectForKey:kNavBarTitleColor] alpha:1.0f];
 UIColor *navBarTitleShadowColor = [UIColor  greenColor];//colorWithHexString:[self.personalityDictionary objectForKey:kNavBarTitleShadowColor] alpha: [navBarTitleShadowOpacity floatValue]];

return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        navBarTitleColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
        navBarTitleShadowColor, UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
        [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
        nil];
  }
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: That's what I'm doing - my AppearanceManager class runs before my navigation controller is set up.